# How to insert a huge file to Large Object (PostgreSQL) without loading the complete file into memory?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, blob

I use Hibernate with Java and PostgreSQL to store huge file into database. I don't want the file to be completely read to the memory because I get Out of memory. probably the best solution will be to read the chunks and push the file content as byte array to my DB BLOB column.

***Entity:***

```
@Lob
@Column
private Blob file;
```

***Download using BinaryStream:***

```
ResourceLibraryModel obj = new ResourceLibraryModel();
InputStream imgStream = obj.getFile().getBinaryStream();
```

***Upload file:***

```
javax.servlet.http.Part part    
InputStream input = part.getFile().getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) output.write(buffer, 0, length);
obj.setFile(output.toByteArray());
```

Can you propose some working solution.

Comment: @Kayaman currently this is the solution that I found. I will be very happy if you show me some code solution.

Comment: Create a stored procedure which inserts a whole file into BLOB field, and then execute it from JDBC with the file name. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/how-to-insert-file-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column

Comment: @VictorGubin It's a very complicated solution. Can you propose some other based on the original question?

Comment: in fact this is 10-15 strings solution.  Forgot to hint to calling stored procedure from Hibernate https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-call-postgresql-function/

Comment: It's a bit tricky since there's JPA messing things about. There are some non-stored procedure Hibernate solutions with `createBlob` easily found when searching SO though.

Comment: @Kayaman can you share a link about this proposal?

Comment: Use the search field and you'll find even more options.

Comment: The solution is to use the Large Object API of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. It allows you to write the LOB in chunks.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you show me code example with Hibernate, please?

Comment: No; I don't do Hibernate. I don't know if there is Large Object support in Hibernate, but I am certain that you can use JDBC from it.